# Serve static files and directory listing in LoopBack

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

Following a [LoopBack tutorial](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Add-a-static-web-page.html#add-an-html-file), I want to modify it to serve a directory listing if the directory does not have an `index.html` or similar.

I have previously done this in Express using:

```
var express = require('express');
var serveIndex = require('serve-index');
var app = express.express();
app.use('/', serveIndex(__dirname + '/public', {}));
app.use('/', express.static('public'));
```

Can I modify `middleware.json` to do this? Alternatively, how could I do this in a LoopBack JS boot script?

I have tried putting the following in a file `routes.js` in the boot directory:

```
module.exports = function(app)
{
    var serveIndex = require('serve-index');
    app.use('/', serveIndex(__dirname + '../client', {}));
    app.use('/', app.static('../client'));
};
```

But it's obviously not the same, since `app.static()` in the first example is not a method on the same object as `use()` - ie the second example produces the error:

> TypeError: app.static is not a function

(Also the paths aren't right, but I'm dealing with one problem at a time)

Answer (score 1):

It was quite straightforward. While I could not find a way to access the express module via the loopback app object, it could simply be `require()`d.

Create the file `./server/boot/routes.js` with the following:

```
module.exports = function(app)
{
    var express = require('express');
    var serveIndex = require('serve-index');

    var croot = __dirname+'/../../client';
    app.use('/', express.static(croot));
    app.use('/', serveIndex(croot, {'icons': true}));
}
```